# page is not opening by giving url django

Tags: python, django

**I am unable to show purchasing template by writing URL "localhost:8000/purchasing" on browser. I am beginner here.**

- projectforms

  - urls.py
- bookingform

  - urls.py
  - views.py

**projectforms.urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('bookingform.urls')),
path('purchasing/', include('bookingform.urls')),
]
```

**bookingform.urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [

path('',views.add_model),
path(r'^purchasing/',views.purchasing_view,name="purchasing"),
]
```

This is the view. I have defined two functions in it.

**bookingform.views**

```
def add_model(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Booking Saved')
        # return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "template.html", {'form': form})


else:

    form = Form()

    # purchaing = purchasing.objects.all()

    return render(request,"template.html",{'form': form})


def purchasing_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        purchasing_form = purchasingform(request.POST)
        if purchasing_form.is_valid():
            purchasing_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Purchaing Record Saved')
            # return redirect('/')
        return render(request, "purchasing.html", {'purchasing_form': 
purchasing_form})


    else:

        purchasing_form = purchasing()

        # purchaing = purchasing.objects.all()

        return render(request, "purchaing.html", {'purchasing_form': 
purchasing_form})
```

Comment: you have not imported bookingform in projectforms.urls import that

Comment: @nishant he does not need to, he is including the urls from `bookingform` dynamically by specifying the import path of the bookingform.urls module as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you want to have the following URL's

`localhost:8000` -> which maps to the `add_model`

`localhost:8000/purchasing` -> which maps to the `purchasing_view`

For this in `projectforms.urls` you need:

```
from bookingform.views import add_model, purchasing_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', add_model),
    path('purchasing', purchasing_view),
]
```